# Join on 2 different conditions based on CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, case

I want to write an update query which joins 2 tables based on different Case conditions

```
Update Table1
Set ID = Case when T1.value1 < 0
          then T2.ID ------Join on value1 between T2.valueTo and T2.ValueFrom
               when T1.value2 > 0
          then T2.ID -------Join on value2 between T2.valueTo and T2.ValueFrom
 from Table1
 Join Table2 t2 on value1 between T2.valueTo and T2.ValueFrom OR value2 between T2.valueTo and T2.ValueFrom
```

The above query doesn't work. Is there a way I can write which join should work based on the case expression.

Comment: its a `case expression` - it can only return a value, not an expression. Check the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two joins, one for each condition:

```sql
Update Table1
Set ID = Case when T1.value1 < 0
          then T2.ID ------Join on value1 between T2.valueTo and T2.ValueFrom
               when T1.value2 > 0
          then T3.ID -------Join on value2 between T2.valueTo and T2.ValueFrom
 from Table1
 Join Table2 t2 on value1 between T2.valueTo and T2.ValueFrom
 Join Table2 t2 on value2 between T3.valueTo and T3.ValueFrom
```